# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Port 80

Tags: docker, docker-compose

have a little issue with Forbidden error when running docker-compose file:

> "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) IP . Port 80"

I'm running Docker on AWS UBUNTU SERVER (not localhost).

there's also `index.php` file (same folder) to connect `mysql`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysqldb
  web:
    image: php:7.2.2-apache
    container_name: web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

**Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Port 80**

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG???????? (chmod/ demoapache.conf)
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have any access to the server's logs? Are you sure that you are accessing the server within that container, and not any other server?

Comment: I'm sure cause when I run docker-compose for any other work, for example: mysql+wordpress and go to the IP of the server (dedicated) I see the result, works OK

Comment: THIS WORKS PERFECT::::::::   ---
services:
  db:
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "1"
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    restart: always
  wordpress:
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
version: "3.1"

Comment: But when I run index.php code against mysql then the error appears.

Comment: Docker logs shows connection from my ip address